# Fancybox open with autplay via secondary link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I am using the free "Fancybox for Wordpress" Plugin to open a Couple of images with a nice lightbox.

Now I have a huge title image saying "show diashow" and all pictures of the gallery underneath as single pics. Clicking the single images opens them how it is supposed to be, beeing able to navigation left/right. 
The problem now is, if I click the huge title image, it should open the first image of the gallery + set it to autoplay. How can I achieve this?

I tried it with this, but it didnt work out:

HTML

```
<a id="diashow" href="/wp-content/gallery/galerie/1457454_10152045202815199_1685986480_n.jpg" rel="fancybox"><img src="/wp-content/themes/kt2014/images/diashow.jpg" alt="Diashow starten" /></a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// START DIASHOW AUTPLAY ON CLICK
        jQuery('#diashow').click(function(evt) {
            jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox.open();
            jQuery.fancybox.play();
        });
});
```

Thanks for every help on this!

Comment: Did you get any messages in the console? And what does it mean it didn't work out?

Comment: If you are using a free "Fancybox for Wordpress", most likely they are sing fancybox v1.3.4 and that version has not an autoplay functionality